Excel Application History gets broken/ empty / reset when updating shapes position with VBA
I am using VBA to position a series of shapes. When this is triggered, the Excel application history becomes empty, i.e. the "Back" and "Forward" buttons are greyed out and inactive.
The script ensures that shapes (which are used as buttons to trigger macros) are positioned in the bottom right corner (similar to a menu that moves along) when something is selected in the sheet. The positioning itself deletes the history. Does anyone have a solution/workaround to preserve the Excel history?
in Worksheet module:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PositionForms
End Sub

in standart module:
Sub PositionForms()
    Dim LastVisibleRow As Long, LastVisibleColumn As Long, Gap As Double
    Dim ShapesArray As Variant
    Dim sh As Shape, shapeName As Variant
    ' determine last cell right bottom
    LastVisibleRow = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Rows(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Rows.Count).Row
    LastVisibleColumn = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Columns(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Columns.Count).Column
    ' array of shapes
    ShapesArray = Array("Sprung_zu_PID(1)", "Sprung_1x_zurück", "Sprung_zu_gesamt", "Explorer_öffnen", "PIDs_entfernen", "PIDs_einfügen", "Backup_Stopp", "Backup_Intervall", "Backup_einmal", "Speichern_unter", "BOM_berechnen", "Update_Kabellaengen", "Update_Steuerungsd", "Import_Steuerungsdaten", "SetZoomLevel")
    ' startposition
    Dim CurrentLeft As Double, CurrentTop As Double
    CurrentLeft = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastVisibleRow, LastVisibleColumn).Left
    CurrentTop = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastVisibleRow, LastVisibleColumn).Top
    For Each shapeName In ShapesArray
        Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(shapeName)
        Gap = 0.225 * sh.Height
        ' right bottom pisitioning
        sh.Left = CurrentLeft - sh.Width
        sh.Top = CurrentTop - sh.Height
        ' update position for next
        CurrentTop = sh.Top - Gap
    Next shapeName
End Sub

I swiched all eventhandlers to false, but this is not the solution.

Isn't it an answer for your question: undo-history-button-clear-after-run-macro-excel

That's the kind of crap I was afraid of. But I didn't find it myself. Microsoft ... :(
Thx
